# How can I include pseudos in a DTM in R?

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to get a DTM of the words on this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Libyan_Civil_War_(2011)/Archive_1

My problem is the pseudos of the person posting (that are words of my corpus) never appear in my DTM even if I am setting dictionary on NULL. For instance, I expect the word "Lihaas" to be found 31 times but it is not showing up on my DTM.

My code :

```
library(tm)
docs<- VCorpus(DirSource(directory = "~dir"))
docsTDM <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs, control=list(dictionary=NULL))
```

I obtain :

```
          the          2011      february           utc 
          628           319           293           280 
         talk           and          this          that 
          236           197           163           152 
          for           are           not      uprising 
          106           101            92            79 
       libyan      protests           but       support 
           76            75            68            68 
         with         there        revolt           its 
           68            65            62            61 
      protest       article          have           now 
           58            57            53            50 
          has         civil        should         which 
           47            46            44            44 
         more         think           war           was 
           43            43            41            41 
         from         libya          what         would 
           40            40            36            35 
        about    revolution         added       sources 
           34            34            32            32 
      comment    government        people          some 
           30            30            30            30 
          all          just       section           you 
           29            29            29            29 
         than      unsigned          will           can 
           27            27            27            26 
talk•contribs          then          even          name 
           26            26            25            25
```

Comment: Sorry the output did not go as expected, the point being from the example I have taken "Lihaas" never shows up

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the fact that "Lihaas" is adjacent to a preceding "." in all of the cases that I see, or inside parentheses.  So it is likely to be due to issues with **tm**'s tokeniser.

Here is an alternative that produces what you want, using the **quanteda** package.

```
# read the document using the readtext package
wikitxt <- readtext::readtext("Talk:Libyan Civil War (2011):Archive 1 - Wikipedia.html")

library("quanteda")
wikidfm <- dfm(corpus(wikitxt), tolower = FALSE)
wikidfm
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 3,006 features (0% sparse).

wikidfm[, c("lihaas", "Lihaas")]
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 2 features (0% sparse).
## 1 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    lihaas Lihaas
##   text1      1     30
```